# I'm trying to understand [class.bit]/1, but I found this strange behavior

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, bit-fields

Consider this snippet:

```
#include<iostream>
struct S {
    int bf1:16, bf2:7;
    char bf3:8;
} s;

struct A{
    int i;
    char c;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(S) << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof(A) << '\n';
}
```

clang and GCC print the following values for the code above (see [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60e3a7395a193220)):

```
4
8
```

That is, it allocates the bit-field `bf3` as if I had defined struct S as follows:

```
struct S{
    int bf1:16, bf2:7, bf3:8
};
```

That doesn't seem to be correct.

Note also, that if I define the bit-field `bf3` with 9 bits, in the original snippet, both compilers emit a warning saying that the 9 bits exceed the width of its type, a `char`, but now they print 8 bytes for the struct S. That's strange, as it's still possible to allocate the 9 bits, as if `bf3` was declared  in the first `int` member of the struct.

I know the Standard says in [[class.bit]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.bit#1) that:

> Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is
>   implementation-defined.

Maybe I'm missing something, but I think there is some inconsistency in the way both compilers are treating this case.

Comment: Seems to be an ABI issue, at least with gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html

Comment: try `int bf1:16, bf2:7, :0;`

Comment: The standard doesn't have anything else to offer, "Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is implementation-defined." really does mean what it says.  If the compiler's documentation of its bitfield behaviour does not match your observation (or if the documentation is inadequate) then report a compiler bug/issue.